# Duda sobre tipo de dato float en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, y ando haciendo ejercicios de tipos de datos. Se supone que tengo que encontrar errores en el código, y aquí tengo:

```
9.-  float f1 = 13.5; 
10.- float f2 = 8f;
```

Realmente tengo un poco de lío, porque no sé si el fallo es que todo tipo `float` lleva una `f` tras el valor como en la línea de código 10, o que realmente no debería llevar esa `f` porque no tenemos ninguna variable que se llame `f`, sino `f1`, y esa `f` significaría: `8*f.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que si al declarar una variable de tipo `float` no se añade la `f` *(literal de coma flotante)* [(ref)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) o no se hace el `cast` a `float` **el tipo predeterminado será `double`** entonces en su línea 9 daría un error de incompatibilidad de tipo de dato, ya que haría falta realizar el `cast` para poder asignar el valor *(dos formas posibles)*

```
float f2 = 13.5; //Error , tipo double
float f2 = (float) 13.5; // correcto
float f2 = 13.5f; // correcto también
```

Answer (score 1):

Las variables de tipo float permiten almacenar números reales, tales como: `5.85, 7.0, 25.023...`, es decir, números con decimales.

Para asignar un valor a una variable tipo float puedes, o bien escribir el número directamente, por ejemplo: `8`; o añadir el sufijo 'f' al número: `8f`, como ocurre en tu ejemplo.

Por tanto, considéralo como dos formas diferentes de declarar una variable float.

Comment: [No se puede asignar directamente el valor](http://rextester.com/NPW27183) `8.0` a un `float` 3:)

Comment: Correcto, se me fue la pinza, edito. Gracias! @Dev.Joel