# No se comparan mis cadenas, Java

Tags: java, string, switch

Tengo este método para seleccionar el nombre del token basado en su numero, este método esta hecho para devolver la descripción de este y ponerlos en una tabla, el problemas es que estos no se comparan correctamente, como pueden observar primero hice una comparación simple con un if utilizando el método equals, pero aunque la cadena sea "-3" no entra, y en el caso del switch también se va al case default, no entra al case de "-3", y por defecto me retorna el "Def". Agradecería mucho si alguien me ayudase a corregir el error.
Update: Quisiera aclarar que el único case que si toma es el "-16"

```
 public String getDescr(String token){
    String nombre="";
    if(token.equals("-3")){
        nombre="Entero";
    }
    
    switch(token){
        case "-1": nombre="Identificador"; break;
        case "-2": nombre="Comentario"; break;
        case "-3": nombre="Entero"; break;
        case "-4": nombre="Exponencial"; break;
        case "-5": nombre="Decimal"; break;
        case "-6": nombre="Texto"; break;
        case "-7": nombre="Caracter"; break;
        case "-8": nombre="Operador"; break;
        case "-9": nombre="Monogamo"; break;
        case "-10": nombre="Logico"; break;
        case "-11": nombre="Relacional"; break;
        case "-12": nombre="Desplazamiento"; break;
        case "-13": nombre="Asignacion"; break;
        case "-14": nombre="Puntuacion"; break;
        case "-15": nombre="Agrupacion"; break;
        case "-16": nombre="Reservada"; break;
        default:nombre="def";
                
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

Comment: He revisado el código y funciona como quieres que funcione, es decir, probé llamando al método `getDescr("-3")` y me devuelve `"Entero"` así que no entiendo cual es el problema. Quizá es que el valor que esta llegando al método no es -3, debe ser un valor que no estas controlando.

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente https://onlinegdb.com/sfAjpAiC6 . Edita tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: Sera algún bug de mi proyecto? Me imprime el nodo que entra en el método, pero no se compara.

Comment: Probablemente estés pasándole otro carácter que no es el guión "-". Nota que el guión - no es lo mismo que el signo de menos  − ni  lo mismo que la raya (—).  Revisa las [diferencias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guion_(signo_ortogr%C3%A1fico)). Pon tu teclado en inglés, eso ayuda bastante a evitar estos errores.

Comment: El código funciona, como bien dice @JESUSCORONEL. ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema que se presenta en tu contexto? Muestra la parte donde llamas al método `getDescr()`.

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responderme, era un error bastante tonto y si venia por mi lado, en vez de estar entrando un -3 entraba un -3.0 y yo ni en cuenta teniéndolo en mis ojos jaja, muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Duda sobre tipo de dato float en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137748/duda-sobre-tipo-de-dato-float-en-java)